Double, triple, and multi-cosets of subgroups
Due to the definition of the double cosets of two subgroups (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_coset), one may naturally ask for three or more subgroups.
Let $H_1,\cdots,H_n$ be subgroups of $G$ and define their multi-cosets by $H_1g_1H_2g_2\cdots H_{n-1}g_{n-1}H_n$ where $g_i\in G$ for $i=1,\cdots,n-1$. If we have a similar property to the set of representatives $X$ of double cosets, we should have subsets (multi-transversals) $X_1,\cdots, X_{n-1}$ of $G$ such that
$$
G=\dot{\bigcup}_{x_1\in X_1,\cdots, x_{n-1}\in X_{n-1}}H_1x_1H_2x_2\cdots H_{n-1}x_{n-1}H_n
$$
where $\dot{\bigcup}$ denotes the disjoint union.
Now, is this true for the multi-cosets (in general)?
I have not found anything else to help with this. Does anybody know any useful references (books, papers, websites) for this matter?
Thanks in advance for your attention.

Left cosets $gH$ of $H$ in $G$ are orbits of the right $H$-action on $G$. Double cosets of $H$ are orbits of the left-right $H\times H$-action on $G$ (and similarly for two subgroups). More general multi-cosets would not even form a partition in general, so I'm not sure they have been much studied.

For $n = 3$, $H_1 = {1}$, the "triple cosets" $xH_2yH_3$ are not disjoint in general. For example take $G = S_3$, $H_2 = H_3$ of order $2$.

Thanks for your comments.

These multicosets do come up in automata theory.  For example, a theorem of Ribes-Zalesski says that all multicosets of finitely generated subgroups of a free group are closed in the profinite topology and this translates to the statement that the closed rational subsets of a free group are precisely finite unions of multicosets of finitely generated subgroups of a free group

Very useful. Thanks.
